# Unity collider touch not act on player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have both `player` and `ground` with colliders 2D and player is supposed to stop on top of `ground` but instead it stops at the bottom of the ground.

[image: one]

## Code

`PlayerController`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    private float moveSpeedStore;
    public float speedMultiplier;
    public float speedIncreateMilestone;
    private float speedIncreateMilestoneStore;
    private float speedMilestoneCount;
    private float speedMilestoneCountStore;
    public float jumpForce;
    public float jumpTime;
    private float jumpTimeCounter;
    private bool stoppedJumping;
    private bool canDoubleJump;
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    public bool grounded;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    // private Collider2D myCollider;
    private Animator myAnimator;
    public GameManager theGameManager;
    public AudioSource jumpSound;
    public AudioSource deathSound;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
        speedMilestoneCount = speedIncreateMilestone;
        moveSpeedStore = moveSpeed;
        speedMilestoneCountStore = speedMilestoneCount;
        speedIncreateMilestoneStore = speedIncreateMilestone;
        stoppedJumping = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);

        if(transform.position.x > speedMilestoneCount)
        {
            speedMilestoneCount += speedIncreateMilestone;
            speedIncreateMilestone = speedIncreateMilestone * speedMultiplier;
            moveSpeed = moveSpeed * speedMultiplier;
        }

        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) )
        {
            if(grounded)
            {
                myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);
                stoppedJumping = false;
                jumpSound.Play();
            }

            if(!grounded && canDoubleJump)
            {
                myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);
                jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
                stoppedJumping = false;
                canDoubleJump = false;
                jumpSound.Play();
            }
        }

        if((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButton(0)) && !stoppedJumping)
        {
            if(jumpTimeCounter > 0)
            {
                myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);
                jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            jumpTimeCounter = 0;
            stoppedJumping = true;
        }

        if(grounded)
        {
            jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
            canDoubleJump = true;
        }

        myAnimator.SetFloat("Speed", myRigidbody.velocity.x);
        myAnimator.SetBool("Grounded", grounded);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "killbox")
        {
            theGameManager.RestartGame();
            moveSpeed = moveSpeedStore;
            speedMilestoneCount = speedMilestoneCountStore;
            speedIncreateMilestone = speedIncreateMilestoneStore;
            deathSound.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

`Player settings`

[image: two]

#### Question

What should I do to hold my player on top of ground?

**NOTE:** it's my first question on `unity` ever so if you need any sort of code or data please just ask, I try my best to provide you what you need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your collider is simply too high. You'll notice that the green box indicating your collider size and position is colliding with the correct spot on the ground. The bottom of it is just touching the top of the ground. You simply need to move the collider down on the player so that the bottom of the green box is at the bottom of the player's sprite.

Comment: Thanks, the normal collider is like this image https://ibb.co/58kvmLV but somehow when player touch the ground it slips out

Comment: but the box collider has `y offset = 1` as we can see if the screenshot. Put that to 0 and try again?

Comment: It's same result I've tried `0` `-0.91` and many more https://ibb.co/PjQtYXq

Comment: Can you select both the ground and player objects then take a screenshot? Also do that in play mode. And show us the collider settings on the ground object.

Comment: here you go `select player and ground`  https://ibb.co/qRtnrYM `select in play mode` https://ibb.co/1mzzKPx  `ground collider` https://ibb.co/Sc9BNJ0

Comment: Well it seems like when switching to play mode, the collider is moving upward before you even hit the ground. I see the thin collider in the center of his body in play mode but at the bottom in edit mode. That leads me to believe that you have a rigidbody on both the player and on the GroundCheck child object. If so, that might be the problem.

Comment: Hi, no I don't have any rigidbody on `GroundCheck`. would you mind read my comment [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-collider-touch-not-act-on-player.974682/#post-6342747)